# v-model and selected is not working at the same time... --vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

### UPDATED

select input's `selected` option is not working if I use v-model on `select`.

```html
<p class="topics">fruits</p>
<select class="select" v-model="selectFruit">
    <option selected value="">--all--</option>
    <option :key="index" :value="item" v-for="(item,index) in fruitList">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

if I don't use v-model, then `selected` is working. But I need that v-model bind for filter my array. But it looks like I can't use v-model and selected at the same time.

Comment: Seems like the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/hcg6z7Lt/) above is working perfectly fine to me. Are you using different (font) color for your options? The background color for your dropdown seems different from the select input itself and it might be that the color of the font might still be white (which causes it to be invisible).

Answer (score 2):

Use selected attribute

> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
   <select class="select" v-model="searchCity">
      <option value="" selected>--全部--</option>
      <option :value="item" v-for="item in uniqueCity">{{item}}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Did you now? Might be worth mentioning then in your question as well @Barbie would you not say so? Remember we are trying to help out here.

Comment: i see only that it's not in the given code so  give code correctly please.

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you have tried to make the select work and tell us what is not working about it? @Barbie

Comment: still i can't see any problem in code. can you add code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bonus to the above answer, if you want to have a default placeholder but not a valid value (Like "Select country here") you can do it like this:

```
  <select>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select country here</option>
  <option value="1">Bulgaria</option>
  <option value="2">Serbia</option>
  <option value="3">Cyprus</option>
  </select>
```